# Missing Added Reference When Using CodeDom Compiler

Tags: c#, dll, system-codedom-compiler

I've found similar questions to this but not managed to find something which specifically addresses my problem yet.

I have some code which edits an Excel workbook via `System.CodeDom.Compiler`. This is important as I want to be able to 'plug-in' different editing instructions for different workbooks later on.

The reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Dll was added to my project using References>Add...  in visual studio and I have added the reference for the excel dll for the CodeDom compiler using `.ReferencedAssemblies.Add` as follows:

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.Dll");
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Dll");
```

But unfortunately, this error occurs:

> {error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Dll' could not be found}

Is there any easy way to tell the CodeDom compiler to find this dll?

I have tried `compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application).Assembly.Location);` as [suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13425227/7858451), but this only points the compiled program exe, and not the required dll.

Thanks, Joe.

Comment: I am struggeling with a similar problem and dont expect this to be the solution, but did you try a lowercase '.dll' ending? (For me loading System.Data works, but only in VS(debug and release), the built host-exe just wont find the dll... no matter what... -.- )

Comment: That's a good point - I have to admit, I didn't try the lower case file extension. I've been severely side tracked since working on this, but if I ever get back to it - I'll certainly give it a try! I'll also feed back on here if it doesn't work and I find an alternative solution.Thanks :)

Comment: I will give this one a try now: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Dec/12/Loading-NET-Assemblies-out-of-Seperate-Folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the answer, but its too much for a comment and could help as a "workaround".

I managed to load System.Data.dll which was NOT part of the hosting-assembly. I placed it in the executing "bin" folder manually, just for testing. 
My mistake was pretty obvious I used: 
`String pathToDll = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;`
to get the base directory of that dll. But I got an uri (file:///C:/...). Once parsed to "C:\..." everything went well.

Since your dll cannot be found you could edit the Properties of that Reference and set "CopyLocal = true", so that the dll will end up in the same path as the .exe .. After that you should be able to load it:

```
String pathAndFile = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;    
pathAndFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathAndFile);
Uri uri = new Uri(pathAndFile);
pathAndFile = uri.LocalPath + "\\" + "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Dll";
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(pathAndFile);
```

Also, take a look at this little piece of code, it *should* load everything from the hosting assembly. (Warning: You cannot load a single assembly twice in the same AppDomain)

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                       .GetAssemblies()
                       .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
                       .Where(a => !parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Contains(a.Location))
                       .Select(a => a.Location);

parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies.ToArray());
```

And as far as I have read, these two tutorials are a bit old (depricated code) but helped me understand thing a little more:

https://west-wind.com/presentations/DynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Dec/12/Loading-NET-Assemblies-out-of-Seperate-Folders